# Calling merge on a hibernate entity returns Javassist proxy objects?

Tags: java, hibernate

Can anyone help with the above situation?

I have an entity `A`, that holds a reference to another entity `B` (mapped as a `OneToOne` relationship). When I call merge on entity `A`, and return this persistent object, entity `B` (when stepping through and debugging) appears as a Javassist object rather than an actual entity object. This makes for terribly confusing debugging...

Is this an option I can switch off? Is it beneficial to me in any way? I've checked Manning's Java Persistence with Hibernate book - it has no mention of Javassist...

Cheers

Comment: JavaAssist is a bytecode manipulation library. As far as I remember hibernate is using this internally. Also it is used frequently by libs like mockito, jacoco and other libraries relying on bytecode instrumentation.

Comment: Hibernate creates proxies which add extra logic to your entities for things like lazy loading etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get `_javaassist`  object(a proxy object), if it is initialized to its related object after session closed.

In your case, try to open a new session, start transaction, and then save the object using `session.save()` to save object. then `session.flush()` and commit transaction.

It will resolve your problem.

If it won't work, I would suggest `Hibernate.initialize(a.getB())` before flushing session.

It'll surely return actual object.